# How do I localise variables in another package when I only know their names at runtime?

Tags: perl

I need to localise some variables in another package, but I won't know what their names are until they are passed in.  My attempts to use `local` with typeglobs didn't work, so I have fallen back to saving the value of the variable and restoring it manually.  Is there a better way?  Note, the error checking to see if a variable exists before mucking with it has been elided for clarity.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %orig;
for my $name (qw/foo bar baz/) {
    my $var = \${$meta::{$name}};
    $orig{$name} = $$var;
    $$var = $$var * 2;
}
meta::p();
for my $name (keys %orig) {
    my $var = \${$meta::{$name}};
    $$var = $orig{$name};
}
meta::p();

package meta;

BEGIN {
    our $foo = 1;
    our $bar = 2;
    our $baz = 3;
}

sub p { print join(" :: ", $meta::foo, $meta::bar, $meta::baz), "\n" }
```

I am trying to avoid an eval like this:

```
my $eval = '';

for my $name (qw/foo bar baz/) {
    $eval .= "local \$meta::$name = \$meta::$name * 2;\n";
}

eval "$eval meta::p()";
meta::p();
```

Is trying to avoid the eval a waste of time?  Is the new code worse than the eval?

Note, I also don't want to use symbolic references, all code must work under `strict`.  The current solution works, so I am not looking for hacks to get around what I am doing, I am looking for a better solution (if one exists).

Answer (score 3):

Turning off `strict refs` should allow you to do what you want with [symbolic references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references).  I don't have access to a system to do a test with ATM, but something like this should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    no strict `refs`;
    local ${"meta::$name"} = ${"meta::$name"} * 2;

    meta::p();
}

meta::p();
```

**Update:**

After some testing, I found a snag.

While it is easy to use `local` on a single symbolic reference.  But to localize an array of variable names is not so simple--the loop constructs (map, for, etc) all create a small, scope around the expression they operate on, which terminates localization.

```
# This works but does not work on an array of names.
{   no strict 'refs';

    local ( ${'meta::foo'}, ${'meta::bar'}, ${'meta::baz'} );
    meta::p();
}
meta::p();


# THIS DOES NOT WORK AT ALL!
{   no strict 'refs';

    my @to_localize = map "meta::$_", qw/foo bar baz/;

    local ${$_} = $$_ * 2 for @to_localize;
    meta::p();

}
meta::p();
```

The only solution I could find uses `goto`, which we all know is *considered harmful*.

```
{   no strict 'refs';

    my @to_localize = map "meta::$_", qw/foo bar baz/;

    LOCALIZER:
        my $localize_me = shift @to_localize;
        local ${$localize_me} = $$localize_me * 2;
        goto LOCALIZER if @to_localize;

    meta::p();

}
meta::p();
```

I'm open to better ideas.

Comment: I should have put in there that I don't want to use symbolic references either.

Comment: I believe that daotoad method is mentioned in "Mastering Perl", or "Advanced Perl".

Comment: @Chas Owens: Why not use symbolic refs?  IMO, using symbolic references in a strictly controlled scope is reasonable.  Many things that, at first, seem to require a string eval can be done by disabling strict refs or strict subs.

Comment: If the variable name they passed in doesn't exist I don't want to created it.  That means mucking with the %package:: anyway.  I also don't like turning off strict.  This solution works fine, but I was hoping I had missed something easy involving local and typeglobs.

Comment: @Chas Owens: If you don't know the variable name until runtime you have no choice but to use symrefs (your variable name *is* in a variable after all) or hand-roll the localization. Lexically disabling strict refs is okay when you understand what you're doing and why. Unfortunately, doing this for a list implies a loop which creates its own block and *that's* a problem. I can't think of a way around that other than string eval.